# TinyMce editor text box not editable

Tags: tinymce

I have a strange problem with the TinyMCE editor on one of our pages. 
The control renders fine but the user is unable to type anything into the text box. And no, it is not locked.
If the user logs on to the same page from another computer then it works! It has something to do with the browser on his machine (IE6/IE8). The page works fine on Firefox on the same machine.

The user initially had IE6 when the problem was reported. The browser was upgraded to IE8, but the problem did not go away.

Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reset the IE settings from Tools > Internet options > Advanced page and it started working! Looks like one of the custom browser settings on the machine messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a javascript error stops tinymce to get initialized properly.
If you use custom plugins - deactivate them (in the init) and see if that helps. If yes find out which plugin is responsible and fix the problem there.

If you do not use custom plugins try to run your tinymce instance with a very basic init and see if this does help.
Try to narrow down for which setting your editor and brwoser do not cooperate.